# Can't start simultaneous tests in Selenoid

Tags: selenoid

I'm working at mac with Apple M1 chip.

Images:

```
aerokube/selenoid:1.10.8
selenoid/firefox:105.0
```

I'm starting selenoid through

```
./cm selenoid start — vnc
```

and selenoid-ui

```
./cm selenoid-ui start
```

If I'm running just one test from my project then everything ok.

But if I run 2 tests simultaneously then I'm getting SESSION_ATTEMPT_TIMED_OUT error. Here is the log:

> [PROXY_TO]
> [2fa920af171e51d860f1624f45a616b60e786d6ca36948c1660952be97b1275c[http://172.18.0.4:4444/wd/hub]
>
> [SESSION_ATTEMPTED] [http://172.18.0.4:4444/wd/hub] [1]
>
> [SERVICE_STARTED]
> [selenoid/firefox:105.0][eccc7924577cdb2b805d51978eafec18b930f1dc33c71ad7c9ce41498001dedb]
>
> [PROXY_TO]
> [eccc7924577cdb2b805d51978eafec18b930f1dc33c71ad7c9ce41498001dedb[http://172.18.0.5:4444/wd/hub]
>
> [SESSION_ATTEMPTED] [http://172.18.0.5:4444/wd/hub] [1]
>
> [SESSION_ATTEMPT_TIMED_OUT] [30s]
>
> [SESSION_FAILED] [http://172.18.0.4:4444/wd/hub] [New session attempts
> retry count exceeded]
>
> [STOPPING_VIDEO_CONTAINER][718987c2275570cc8c49d22185023eb1f30adbcbdc7932a7432b71313e703c2f]
>
> [SESSION_ATTEMPT_TIMED_OUT] [30s]
>
> [SESSION_FAILED] [http://172.18.0.5:4444/wd/hub] [New session attempts
> retry count exceeded]

Why it happens ? And what I need to fix ?

Answer (score 0):

Selenoid never officially supported Mac M1. To deliver this we need to rebuild browser images using official Linux packages for ARM64. For example, for Google Chrome no such packages exist.